# How to get keys from the value in redis

Tags: redis, node-redis

I have checked following, but didn't work.

https://redis.io/commands/keys

> **KEYS Room:***
>
> 1) "Room:120"
>
> 2) "Room:121"
>
> 3) "Room:122"

Following is the redis key/values (HMSET)

**Room:120** [**SocketId**:mOQDJusPjDTBN5L-AAAC,**TimeStamp**:10-10-2017 12:10:00 AM]

**Room:121** ....

**Room:122** ....

...

> Need to search as Room:* SocketId:mOQDJusPjDTBN5L-AAAC

How can I search for SocketId in the collection ?

**Need to search with:**

> *mOQDJusPjDTBN5L-AAAC*

Answer (score 0):

The question is not so clear

as u mentioned hmset i am assuming that you are using hashes to store your data.
As per your data,

'room120' should be the key, 'socketId' should be the field and 'mOQDJusPjDTBN5L-AAAC' should be the value.

so in order to search for socketId you can use hscan,where hscan iterates through the field of a particular key.https://redis.io/commands/scan

in case if you are just using key/value storage i.e

'socketId' being the key ,'mOQDJusPjDTBN5L-AAAC'  being the value.

here u can just use the command  `Keys *socket*`to search for the key  socketId

Comment: Yes,  I am using Hashes to store data. I am looking for , how can I search with 'mOQDJusPjDTBN5L-AAAC' which result as "Room:120 [SocketId:mOQDJusPjDTBN5L-AAAC,TimeStamp:10-10-2017 12:10:00 AM]" ?